# JavaScript Function to Style Background Color

Tags: javascript, function, background

Why doesn't my code work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function barFix(newDiv)
                {
                     var elem = document.getElementById(newDiv);
                     elem.style.background='#666666';
                }
            </script>

                <div onmouseover="barFix('badgebar1');" id="badgelist">                             
                </div>

            <div id="badge1bar" style="background-color: #dddddd; width: 2px; height: 42px;"> </div>
```

I've tried everything.. can't get it working! Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Onmouseover, you're sending 'badgebar1' as a parameter, but there's no badgebar1, it's badge1bar.

So either change the id, or the onmouseover code, then it should work.

Comment: Also that div is 2 pixels wide. It might be hard to see the effect when it does work.